# How to quickly replace a Maven Dependency with an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, m2eclipse

I have setup a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse using Maven. The Web Project has a lot of dependencies to other JARs. The JARs are properly added to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder in Maven/Eclipse. Many of the JARs though are results of other plain Java projects. I want to have the JARs represented by their resepective Java projects in Eclipse from time to time (but not for all of them).

So how do I quickly replace a normal Maven Dependency JAR by its Eclipse project?

Currently I:

1. Remove the Maven Dependency (Right click on the JAR, Maven -> Exlude Maven Artifact)
2. Edit the Build path and add the corresponding Eclipse project
3. Mark the project also in the "Export and Order" section of the Build path
4. Edit the Deployment Assembly properties and add the Eclipse project there as well (so it goes into `WEB-INF/lib` at runtime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your web projects is a maven project (little "m" in the upper left corner) and you have installed the M2E-WTP plugin (included in the Keplar JavaEE package), this will happen automatically, i.e. when the dependent project is open in the workspace, it will be a project link, if it is closed, your web project will use the jar file as dependency.

Comment: How does Eclipse know which project corresponds to which jar file? Is there any naming convention?

Comment: It keeps a list of all projects with their corresponding Maven coordinates (`$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/workspacestate.properties`). However, I just read from your comment at the other answer that you are still using Maven 1, which is extremely outdated and not supported in modern IDEs anymore. So, my first and foremost suggestion is: convert your projects to Maven 2/3 (and please: do not mix maven 1 and maven 2 projects)

Comment: I am in a progress of converting from maven 1 to maven 3. Your answers make me confident that my setup becomes easier then. Thank you!

Comment: I now converted one of the Java Projects to a Maven 3 project. So it is having a pom.xml and I am able to import it as a Maven project into Eclipse. But the Dependencies of the other mavenized dynamic web project that uses the Java project did not change automatically. Is it maybe because the Java project has version `SNAPSHOT`whereas the web project depends on version `2.6.0`? Is it possible to configure Eclipse to ignore the version number?

Comment: No. The coordinates must match exactly.

Comment: Thank you. So I mark this answer as the correct one: When having all involved projects as Maven projects and if group Id, artifact id and version match it works out of the box. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using M2Eclipse, I gess you should enable *Workspace resolution*.
Both projects should be maven projects.

If you're using mvn eclipse plugin, make sure, they both have a pom.xml and call :

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

Comment: I did not know the _Workspace resolution_ feature. Thanks for the hint. I will look into it. Currently the plain java projects are still built by Maven 1. So maybe this is a problem.

Comment: Do I need to actively turn on the _Workspace Resolution_? I did not find a setting for it.

Comment: I'm not sure but something like : right clic on your maven project (managed by M2Eclipse) > maven > enable Workspace resolution

Comment: Thank you. It turned out that it was in fact enabled, but the project's version differed from the Maven Dependency in the other project. After I changed it to be the same version number (SNAPSHOT), it worked.